# How to apply new Locale in Android to current screen

Tags: android, localization, locale

I have implemented an option to select GUI language in my app, but I can't make it refresh the screen when a new language is selected.
The selection is made through a `ListPreference` so there are 2 problems :
1. Refresh the `Preference` page in which the language is selected.
2. When the app starts, I set the `Locale` on the `onCreate()` of the `MainActivity` but the `MainActivity` layout is never getting updated with the new selected Locale. (all other screens are updated so the set code is good).

Here is the code for setting the new Locale :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);

    String langKey = ctx.getString(R.string.shared_options_select_language_key);
    String langDefault = ctx.getString(R.string.shared_options_select_language_default_value);
String appLanguage = preferences.getString(langKey, langDefault);

Locale locale = null;
if (appLanguage.equals(langDefault)) {                
    locale = new Locale(Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage());
} else {
    String[] languageInfo = appLanguage.split("_");
    if (languageInfo.length > 1) {
        locale = new Locale(languageInfo[0], languageInfo[1]);
    } else {
        locale = new Locale(appLanguage);
    }
}
if (appLanguage.contains(currentLang)) {
    return false;
}
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;

act.getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, act.getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer would be to position the call to `setLocale` right before setting the screen content :

```
setLocale();
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh the MainActivity after selecting the new Locale

use this to reload the main activity or any activity

```
public void refrehs_me()
{
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Edit : As I can get from your explanation above you save the new locale selected in a shared preference.

Make a new boolean key in the shared preference called (locale_changed) - when a user select a new locale set this key to (TURE) and on the onCreate after setting the new locale check for this key if (TRUE) set it to (FALSE) and reload the activity.

on the second go it will not loop as the key remains (FALSE) until a user change the locale preference again.

Comment: The problem is it will do this in loops since I set the Locale each time. Is the Locale saved so I can check if the `setLocale` is required ?

Comment: Why not just prevent the UI from "refreshing" if the Locale == same as previous.

Comment: I tried getting `previous` by using `getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage()` but it always returns `EN` and not the set language, like the `Locale` is reset when exiting the app.

Comment: After answer edit : The problem is not after selecting new lang, but when setting the the new Locale in the `onCreate()`, and if I `refresh()` I have to re-set the Locale or it returns to default.

Comment: A work around this, which is a bit not pretty but might solve your issue is to create a new activity (StartUp.class) that sets your locale and starts your current MainActivity and finish it self.

Comment: @Osama_Almaani, is it really what all the app devs do ? It really sounds like it will work but a bit 'ungly', I'm sure there is a better way...